# How to show that $B(t) - \mu t$ is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

How is it possible to show that $B(t) - \mu t$ is a martingale. We of course want to show that $E[B(t) - \mu t \,|\, \mathcal{B}_s] = B(s)$, and I'm sure we'd do this using the fact that Brownian increments are independent. How could one show this is the case? Here $B(t)$ is a standard brownian motion and $\mathcal{B}$ is  the Borel $σ$-field, $\mu$ is the drift.

Thus far I have that:

$E[B(t) - \mu t \,|\, \mathcal{B}_s] = E[B(t) + B(s) - B(s) - \mu t \,|\, \mathcal{B}_s]  $

$= E[B(t) - B(s) \,|\, \mathcal{B}_s] + E[B(s) - \mu t \,|\, \mathcal{B}_s] $

$=E[B(s) - \mu t \, | \, \mathcal{B}_s]$

However I am unsure where to take it from here.

Comment: What is $B(t)$?

Comment: @SumanChakraborty a standard Brownian Motion

Comment: If I am understanding your problem correctly then $B(t)-\mu t$ is not a martingale, as $E[B(t) - \mu t \,|\, \mathcal{B}_s] = B(s)-\mu t$.

Comment: @DPJDPJ If drift there is, it's no longer standard Brownian motion

Comment: To answer your question, the increment $B(t) - B(s)$ has same distribution as $B(t-s)$ and  $B(t) - B(s)$ is independent from $B_s$ $\sigma$-algebra, thus it's regular expectation, and you can conclude what you want.